# Cropping an image in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm using tkinter and I have a "sprite sheet" and I want to cut it into multiple images. I tried PIL:

```
img = Image.open("test.png").convert("RGBA")
img2 = img.crop([300,300,350,350])
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
win = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(win, image = image)
label.pack()
```

but on my window, there is only an empty white rectangle and I don't understand why. Moreover I tried `img2.show()` just to make shure that img2 wasn't empty and it wasn't.

Comment: What happens if you start Tkinter before you make the PhotoImage? That is, put the `win =` line before the `image =` line.

Comment: Wow it's realy strange but I were right thx !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your code, with a few changes. Note the call to Tk() at the top, and mainloop() at the bottom.  The other modification is that it obtains the width and height of the image and then crops 25% from each of the four sides to leave the middle 50% of the image.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from tkinter import *  
from PIL import ImageTk,Image  

root = Tk()

img = Image.open("test.png").convert("RGBA")

w, h = img.size

left = w/4
right = 3*w/4
upper = h/4
lower = 3*h/4

img2 = img.crop([ left, upper, right, lower])
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)

label = Label(root, image = image)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```